# Balanced Brackets using stack

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, c++14

I write this code for checking for balanced brakets  (ex.  "{([])}" is balanced and "{([)]}" is not balanced). I am not understanding what is wrong with my code ..please help
here function isBalanced recieves string s and returns YES if string is balanced and NO if it's not
.This question is from hackerrank- https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem

```
string isBalanced(string s) {
stack<char> comp;
char temp;
int i;
for(i=s.size()-1;(s[i]=='}' ) || (s[i]==')' ) || (s[i]==']');i--)
{
    comp.push(s[i]);
}

if(comp.size()!=i+1)
return ("NO");

while(!comp.empty() && i>=0)
{
    temp=comp.top();
    if(temp!=s[i])
    return ("NO");
    comp.pop();
    i--;
}

return("YES");
}
```

Comment: What is your debugger telling you?

Comment: What happens with `"()()"`?

Comment: no "() ()" is not balanced once '(' or '{' or '[' arrived no closing bracket like } should be on its left...i hope you got it  @stark

Comment: Its showing your code giving wrong aswers like for test cases {[()]}    {[(])}   {{[[(())]]}}   its giving output NO   NO   NO  which should be  YES   NO    YES    because first and last one is balanced  @Evg

Comment: @Evg actually giving NO for every test case

Comment: What about `"([)]"?

Comment: You don't need a stack for this problem.

Comment: Two brackets are considered to be a matched pair if the an opening bracket (i.e., (, [, or {) occurs to the left of a closing bracket (i.e., ), ], or }) of the exact same type. There are three types of matched pairs of brackets: [], {}, and ().
A matching pair of brackets is not balanced if the set of brackets it encloses are not matched. For example, {[(])} is not balanced because the contents in between { and } are not balanced. The pair of square brackets encloses a single, unbalanced opening bracket, (, and the pair of parentheses encloses a single, unbalanced closing square bracket, ].

Comment: @john Yes i Know there can be many ways, but i want to do this using stacks and i am not understanding what's wrong in the code

Comment: `()()` is balanced by definition. If not, that definition of "balanced" is certainly broken.

Comment: No dear...() () is not balanced because inside content between left most ( and right most ) i.e  ) (   is not balanced  ..i commented the definition already ..please refer to that.. @Evg

Comment: My code that treats `()()` as balanced passes all test cases there. I guess your understanding of what a balanced sequence is is wrong.

Comment: @Evg Ok dear.. can you please show the code

Comment: Sure: https://pastebin.com/JX1Bd01H